# is there a way to swap around elements in a nested list given there are multiple points of crossover- python

Tags: python, list

I have a nested list as follows:

```
d4 = [[[a11, b11], [a12, b12]], 
      [a21, b21], [a22, b22]]]
```

It is meant to represent alleles at two loci (b is an outer loci and a is the inner loci), on 4 sister chromatids for 2 homologous chromosomes. [a11, b11] are two alleles (on the a and b loci) on  chromatid 1. This chromatid has a duplicate but on the second chromatid [a12, b12]. The first two chromatid make up the first chromosome. Similarly, [[a21, b21], [a22, b22]] are two sister chromatids (techanically 3, 4) which together make up chromosome 2. Chromatid 1 pairs with chromatid 3 and 2 pairs with 4 for recombination.

The way we are looking at it is recombination can occur at the b [[a11,**b11**],...,[a21,**b21**]] locus of pair 1 (this we call recomb_r1). The result would be [[[a11, b21], [a12, b12], [a21, b11], [a22, b22]]], essentially a swap of the b's. recomb_r2 refers to the same thing but between the b's of pair 2 [[a12, **b12**],...,[a22, **b22**]). recomb_r3 refers to a swap between the a's of the first pairs (but as the a locus is lower on the chromosome the b locus swap with it). If recomb_r3 would occur 1 outcome could be [[[a21, b21], [a12, b12], [a11, b11], [a22, b22]]]. Similarity the same could happen for pair 2 [[a12, b12],...,[a22, b22]], which we call recomb_r4. All 4 recombination events can eitther happen or not happen ( we assigned with 0=not happens, 1= happens)

we used this code to determine all the possible outcomes of the 4 recombination events either happening or not.

```
events_b_list = []
for recomb_r1 in [0,1]:
    if (recomb_r1 == 0):
        p_1 = (1-r)
    else:
        p_1 = r
    for recomb_r2 in [0,1]:
        if (recomb_r2 == 0):
            p_2 = (1-r)
        else:
            p_2 = r
        for recomb_r3 in [0,1]:
            if (recomb_r3 == 0):
                p_3 = (1-r)
            else:
                p_3= r
            for recomb_r4 in [0,1]:
                if (recomb_r4 == 0):
                    p_4 = (1-r)
                else:
                    p_4= r
                events=[recomb_r1, recomb_r2, recomb_r3, recomb_r4]
                p = p_1 * p_2* p_3* p_4
                events_b_list.append([events,p])
```

the outcome looks like this, with there associated probabilities (not very important)

```
[[[0, 0, 0, 0], (1 - r)**4],
 [[0, 0, 0, 1], r*(1 - r)**3],
 [[0, 0, 1, 0], r*(1 - r)**3],
 [[0, 0, 1, 1], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[0, 1, 0, 0], r*(1 - r)**3],
 [[0, 1, 0, 1], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[0, 1, 1, 0], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[0, 1, 1, 1], r**3*(1 - r)],
 [[1, 0, 0, 0], r*(1 - r)**3],
 [[1, 0, 0, 1], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[1, 0, 1, 0], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[1, 0, 1, 1], r**3*(1 - r)],
 [[1, 1, 0, 0], r**2*(1 - r)**2],
 [[1, 1, 0, 1], r**3*(1 - r)],
 [[1, 1, 1, 0], r**3*(1 - r)],
 [[1, 1, 1, 1], r**4]]
```

The goal is for the original genotype to go through each possible event and generate a list of the result with all the swaps and such.

Comment: The question is unclear. (Why is the data duplicated inside `d4`? If it's not duplicated - ie. the first `a1` and second `a1` do not contain the same data - use different names! Every time you mention `a1` or some other variable, it's unclear which one you're referring to.) While it's good to have context to what you're doing, the majority of people here aren't biologists - so also explain it such that a non-biologist can follow it. What data type are the variables? What do you want to do to the data? What is the output you want? I can't see how the "possible outcome" relates to the input.

Comment: (If you just wanted to automatically generate the "possible outcome", that's easy, but I can't see how that relates in any way to the rest of the question: You can seemingly generate that with only the knowledge that the number of recombinations is 4, without needing `d4` at all)

Comment: Thank you for the input! Ive tried to clarify the question with more details.

Comment: It's slightly clearer, but still hard to follow. Even if you will use duplicate data as the input, for explaining how it should work, I feel like it'd make more sense to have unique names for each item. (For example, `d4 = [[[a11, b11], [a12, b12]], [a21, b21], [a22, b22]]]`) If I deciphered it correctly, you want to pair `a11` with `a21`, `b11` with `b21`, `a12` with `a22` and `b12` with `b22` - or in general `X1Y` with `X2Y`, ie. `d4[0][Y][X]` with `d4[1][Y][X]`. But you still haven't really explained what you want to happen - you say that "recombination events can happen or not happen", ->

Comment: but you haven't explained what it *means* for a recombination event to happen. Based on the title and some guesswork, presumably if a "recombination event happens", you want to swap the items in the corresponding pair?

Comment: The unique names does sounds easier to fallow, I will change it! I really appreciate the help as Im very new to working with python.

Comment: Yes! if recomb_r1 were to occur there would be recombination event between the b locus for chormatid 1 and 3 or [a11,b11] and [a21, b21]. If it occurs (1) then the changed list would like this [[[a11, b21], [a12, b12], [a21, b11], [a22, b22]]].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, there are lot shorter ways of generating the events and probabilities. The possible events are essentially all 4-bit numbers in binary - or all permutations of 0 and 1 of length 4. So you could either do `for number in range(2**4)` and extract the bits of each number to form the events list, or just use `itertools.product()`:

```
for events in itertools.product([0, 1], repeat=4):
    ones = events.count(1)
    zeros = 4 - ones
    p = r**ones * (1 - r)**zeros
```

As for the swapping, you could do `d4[0][y][x], d4[1][y][x] = d4[1][y][x], d4[0][y][x]` for each `recomb_rR`, you'd just have to create a mapping from each `R` to the proper `y` and `x` indexes. But you'd be modifying the original `d4`, and since you want all the possibilities -- so you'll need separate copies of the lists anyway -- you might as well create the swapped versions from scratch: Just create a new one, where instead of eg. `a11` you have `d4[recomb_r3][0][0]` - for the first 4 items you'd have `recomb_rR` as the first index, and for the last 4 you'd have the complement, so that if `recomb_rR` is 0, the corresponding items will come from their original places in the nested list, but if it's 1, they will get swapped.

Of course, if you can freely change the format of `d4` and the ordering of the recombinations (ie. which recombination number means which pair, or how they are ordered in `events`), you can make your life *much* easier by using `d4 = [[a11, b11, a12, b12], [a21, b21, a22, b22]]` and having the recombination order match `events`; Then you could just do `result = [[d4[c^r][i] for i, r in enumerate(events)] for c in (0, 1)]`.

Comment: Hey thanks for the help! just a fallow up tho, when i go to do d4[0][y][x], d4[1][y][x] = d4[1][y][x], d4[0][y][x] it gives an error saying y is undefined, so Im wondering how i should define it. And also Im uncertain on how to go about mapping from R to the proper x and y. Thank you in advance!

Comment: @Asiv: Your `d4` is a 3-deep nested list, so you need 3 indexes to refer to an item. The first index (for the outermost list) selects the chromosome, the second index (`y`) selects the chromatid, and the third and last index (`x`, for the innermost list) selects the loci. So since `recomb_r1` means you want to swap the second loci (`x = 1`) of the first chromatid (`y = 0`) between the two chromosomes, that's your answer for that `R`. But like I said, you can't use the swap (without doing a nested copy from `d4` first), so you might as well construct the swapped result directly.